# Languge support for Gujrati and Hindi in android

Tags: android

Hi any body know how we can support Hindi and Gujrati Languge support in android. I used below code but it is not supported, I see only box.

I put string file in `res/values-hi/string.xml` folder. There is some key value for Hindi language. It is used for Hindi Language:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("hi");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;     
getBaseContext().getResources()
                .updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Anyone knows than please give me solution.

Comment: Hi Check the solution i had provided before

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450866/how-to-set-gujarati-for-textview-in-the-android-application/22629803#22629803

Answer (score 8):

As gujarati and hindi languages are not supported by Android, you can still give that support to your Application.

For Gujarati copy the `C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\Shruti.TTF` file to your Assets folder [click here to know how to make assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34315335/10258378)
then use the following code.

```
TextView text_view = new TextView(this);

Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Shruti.TTF");

text_view.setTypeface(font);

text_view.setText("ગુજરાતી");
```

`Shruti.TTF` file is for Gujarati font.
Similarly you can add support for hindi file.

Comment: hindi is supported from android version 2.3

Answer (score 2):

Hindi and many other Indian langy=uages are not supported in Android. Though HTC is planning to provide support for some Indian languages.[Read Here.](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/news/htc-brings-indian-language-support-to-android-smartphones-244193)

Now, the code you used to put Hindi text in your app will only work if the Android phone has built in support for Hindi language.

You need to embed Hindi fonts in your app as Kri said.

Answer (score 0):

Hindi reading method in opera mini 1 - First install latest version of "Opera Mini" on Android powered tablet or phone which is available free on Android Market. Otherwise go to official site of opera. (Read about Opera Mini & download) 2 - After that go to address bar & type opera:config and nothing should have www or http://. 3. Then come to the menu & at its end see "use bitmap fonts for complex scripts". No sentence will be written in front of. You change it to Yes. 4. Save it. Now Open any Hindi site and see hindi font on your mobile / tablet instead of square font.

Your can try the following also… Install Hindi font (including all Indian language) as system font - go this link:- http://android-bucket.blogspot.com/2011/07/hindi-font-installation-for-advance.html (Only for Advance users)