# Facebook post in multiple Languages

Tags: android, facebook

I am working on android app in which i am supporting 7 Indian languages.
when i select language to Hindi and perform Facebook post then its not showing Hindi text(all blank) on Facebook wall, but when i did it with English text then its showing all text.

so anyone guide me how can i show post in another languages in Facebook wall.

below is the code which is used by me

```
                .setMessage("राष्ट्रीय")
                .setName("Android Application.")
                .setCaption("One App with 7 language support.")
                .setDescription(
                        "This is dummy app")
                .setPicture(
                        "http://xxxxx.xxxxx.xxx/img/cm/mainhp/logo.gif")
                .setLink("https://www.google.com").build();
        mSimpleFacebook.publish(feed, onPublishListener);
```

after posting this i am getting message as a blank in facebook wall page

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636714/languge-support-for-gujrati-and-hindi-in-android

Answer (score 0):

After 3 hour find solution by my self

```
public static void updateLanguage(Context context, String code)
    {
        Locale locale = new Locale(code);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

and the key point to call in onCreate is

```
Utils.updateLanguage(getApplicationContext(), "hi");
```

where hi is the language code for Hindi.