# Adding an assets folder in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio has changed its project structure yet again... now it is

```
project
└── app-module
    ├── manifests
    ├── res
    └── java
```

I've been looking everywhere online, but I can't find where to put the assets folder. When I try to create the folder via the directory viewer in Android Studio (right-click, New... directory) the "directory" option is not available. The only available options are:

```
Java Class
File
Module
Package
Image Asset
```

None of which will do what I want here.

Has anyone figured this out?

Comment: This is the complete answer with image guidance
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio#27673773)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can click on the Project window, press Alt-Insert, and select Folder->Assets Folder. Android Studio will add it automatically to the correct location.

You are most likely looking at your Project with the new(ish) "Android View". Note that this is a **view** and not the actual folder structure on disk (which hasn't changed since the introduction of Gradle as the new build tool). You can switch to the old "Project View" by clicking on the word "Android" at the top of the Project window and selecting "Project".

Comment: You can also do this in the "Android view": right click on the name of the module where you want the assets folder and navigate to New -> Folder -> Assets Folder.

Comment: I tried to create assets folder manually didn't work, had to follow above procedure :D Thanks

Comment: Thank you this is very simple and straight forward way doing

Answer (score 187):

An image of how to in Android Studio 1.5.1.

Within the "Android" project (see the drop-down in the topleft of my image), Right-click on the app...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I wasted about 10 minutes clicking everywhere looking for this

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Picture is indeed worth a thousand words :)

Answer (score 16):

According to new `Gradle based build system`. We have to put `assets` under `main` folder.

> Or simply right click on your project and create it like

**File > New > folder > assets Folder**

Comment: I haven't noticed any restriction in regards to where you can place an assets folder. Is the `src/main/assets` a special case?

Comment: your asset folder must be under src/main/

Comment: Consider my answer below, I'm adding *an asset folder* directory which does not reside in `src/main/`. It works

Answer (score 6):

To specify any additional asset folder I've used this with my Gradle. This adds `moreAssets`, a folder in the project root, to the assets.

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main.assets.srcDirs += '../moreAssets'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

right click on app-->select

> New-->Select Folder-->then click on Assets Folder