# Save file from android project folder to sd card or internal memory

Tags: android

Is it possible to keep a file(.txt or .pdf) in my android project folder and add its link in some activity, so that when clicked the file from my project folder is downloaded(or saved) to users sd card on internal memory ??

Comment: Yes, use an assets folder. Place your files there. No need to copy to SD card.   http://stackoverflow.com/a/34315335/2308683

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can,

put file(s) in your asset folder and use below solution for copy them to sdcard or internal memory
[How to copy files from 'assets' folder to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sdcard)

Comment: Could you please vote to close question as a duplicate? Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help