# How to get local video Uri for ExoPlayer 2.x

Tags: android, android-video-player, exoplayer

I have a dog.mp4 video file in `res/raw` folder, which I want to play with ExoPlayer. I'm trying to figure out how to get video Uri for this line of code from ExoPlayer developers guide (https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html):

```
MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mp4VideoUri,
    dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
```

To get it, I use this line:

```
Uri mp4VideoUri = Uri.parse("android.resources://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.dog);
```

Also tried this syntax: `android.resource://[package]/[res type]/[res name]`

But `SimpleExoPlayerView` stays black and I get following error:

```
com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: Unable to connect to android.resources://lt.wilkas.deleteexoplayer/2131099648
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would also appreciate any simple tutorial how to play local video with ExoPlayer. Demo app on developers site is quite complicated for me to grasp everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found out that `res/raw` folder cant be used to store local videos for ExoPlayer. They should be placed in `assets` folder.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the solution you came up with?

Comment: As answer says, videos must reside in special folder "Assets". To add this folder, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706843/adding-an-assets-folder-in-android-studio

Comment: You can check my comment that below to this post. Hope I'll create the tutorial on exo in maybe some days.

Answer (score 13):

According to ExoPlayer **2.12** its even easier to use `MediaItem`.
To create it we need `Uri` that could be generated from `RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri`.
And that's it. Just set this `MediaItem` do `prepare()` and play when ready:

```
SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(view.context).build().apply {
    val uri = RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(R.raw.video)
    setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(uri))
    prepare()
    playWhenReady = true
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Don't move your videos from raw to any another folder

Use this code to play video:

```
    PlayerView playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);

    SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);

    // Bind the player to the view.
    playerView.setPlayer(player);

    // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "yourApplicationName"));

    // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
    MediaSource firstSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(R.raw.dog));

    // Prepare the player with the source.
    player.prepare(firstSource);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it as MediaItem, this code work for me (kotlin)

```
val localMediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(
        RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(R.raw.your_video)
    )
```

then

```
player.setMediaItem(localMediaItem)
player.prepare()
```

Answer (score 1):

**res/raw** folder can be used to access local video file for **ExoPlayer** via it's URI. Here's the solution that will not give the **Malformed URL exception** and it works for me. You have to use **RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(R.raw.video)** method of the **RawResourceDataSource** class. Keep in mind that i used the **2.8.0** version of ExoPlayer.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

PlayerView playerView;
SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    playerView=findViewById(R.id.playerView);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    simpleExoPlayer= ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this,new DefaultTrackSelector());
    DefaultDataSourceFactory defaultDataSourceFactory=new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this,"yourApplicationName"));
    simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    ExtractorMediaSource extractorMediaSource=new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(defaultDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(R.raw.video));
    simpleExoPlayer.prepare(extractorMediaSource);
    playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);

    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    playerView.setPlayer(null);
    simpleExoPlayer.release();
    simpleExoPlayer=null;
    super.onStop();
}
```

}

Comment: update yourself exoplayer `2.11.7` has released and your still with `2.8.*`

Comment: I absolutely know that. I am getting some issues with the later version and this version is getting my job done therefore i used this one.

Comment: But i was unable to play `MKV` video with your code and also tried with latest version still i was unable to play.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/63101825/3836908 lie this question

Answer (score 0):

here is the sample to load video/audio file from res/raw with ExoPlayer :

```
val player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context,DefaultTrackSelector())

val rawDataSource = RawResourceDataSource(context)

rawDataSource.open(DataSpec(RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(R.raw.brown)))

val mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(DataSource.Factory { rawDataSource })
    .createMediaSource(rawDataSource.uri)

player.playWhenReady = true
player.prepare(mediaSource)
```

[sample copied from](https://gist.github.com/davidalbers/bddea847f786932c79b781b6e22dfd33)

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

```
fun buildMediaSourceRaw() : MediaSource{
        val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, "exoPlayer")
        val uri = RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(R.raw.my_video)
        return ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri)
    }
```

Then

```
player?.prepare(buildMediaSourceRaw())
```