# Unable to play MKV Matroska video with exoPlayer 2.11

Tags: java, android, exoplayer2.x

In my video player when i try to play `MKV Matroska` file it stay still the video is not playing.

i followed [CodeLabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/#7) and [ExoPlayer Dev](https://exoplayer.dev/) and build player it can play `.MP4` but unable to play `.MKV`

here is my player:`(exoplayer 2.11.5)`

```
private void initializePlayer() {
    if (player == null) {
        player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
        playerView.setPlayer(player);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(videoUri));
        MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
        player.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition);
        player.addListener(playbackStateListener);
        player.prepare(mediaSource, false, false);
    }
}

private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, "exoplayer-codelab");
    @C.ContentType int type = Util.inferContentType(uri);
    switch (type) {
        case C.TYPE_DASH:
            return new DashMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
        case C.TYPE_SS:
            return new SsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
        case C.TYPE_HLS:
            return new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
        case C.TYPE_OTHER:
            return new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported type: " + type);
    }
}
```

Show how should i play `MKV` video using exoplayer. All files are local files from storage.

I even tried following method:

```
    private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, "exoplayer-codelab") ;
            return new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
    }
}
```

In logcat i see this error:

> 2826-3120/com.example.jlplayer E/ACodec: [OMX.google.hevc.decoder] setPortMode on output to DynamicANWBuffer failed w/ err -1010

> EDIT:

after multiple research here is what i tried https://github.com/sanoj26692/pay/blob/master/player

here is the file am trying to play in offline mode. http://jell.yfish.us/media/jellyfish-3-mbps-hd-h264.mkv

**and here is my logcat:**

```
2020-08-17 01:36:23.384 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo V/AudioManager: playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
    
    --------- beginning of system
2020-08-17 01:36:23.427 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/HwCust: Create obj success use class android.app.HwCustActivityImpl
2020-08-17 01:36:23.430 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/HwCust: Create obj success use class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
2020-08-17 01:36:23.432 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo V/ActivityThread: ActivityThread,callActivityOnCreate
2020-08-17 01:36:23.455 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/HwRTBlurUtils: check blur style for HwPhoneWindow, themeResId : 0x7f1000fc, context : com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo.PlayerActivity@b211450, Nhwext : 0, get Blur : disable with , null
2020-08-17 01:36:23.456 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/HwRTBlurUtils: check blur style for HwPhoneWindow, themeResId : 0x7f1000fc, context : com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo.PlayerActivity@b211450, Nhwext : 0, get Blur : disable with , null
2020-08-17 01:36:23.555 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo I/ExoPlayerImpl: Init cb3d2e5 [ExoPlayerLib/2.11.7] [HWPRA-H, PRA-AL00X, HUAWEI, 26]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.562 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo V/AudioManager: registerAudioFocusListener...
2020-08-17 01:36:23.565 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger: state [eventTime=0.01, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, true, BUFFERING]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.567 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/ActivityThread: add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{b53b861 token=android.os.BinderProxy@862c24d {com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo.PlayerActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@862c24d
2020-08-17 01:36:23.578 10937-10978/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
2020-08-17 01:36:23.581 10937-11127/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/MediaCodecInfo: NoSupport [sizeAndRate.support, 1920x1080x-1.0] [OMX.IMG.MSVDX.Decoder.HEVC, video/hevc] [HWPRA-H, PRA-AL00X, HUAWEI, 26]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.581 10937-10945/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 5MB to compile void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
2020-08-17 01:36:23.583 10937-11127/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/MediaCodecInfo: NoSupport [sizeAndRate.support, 1920x1080x-1.0] [OMX.IMG.MSVDX.Decoder.HEVC, video/hevc] [HWPRA-H, PRA-AL00X, HUAWEI, 26]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.588 10937-11127/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/MediaCodecInfo: NoSupport [sizeAndRate.support, 1920x1080x-1.0] [OMX.IMG.MSVDX.Decoder.HEVC, video/hevc] [HWPRA-H, PRA-AL00X, HUAWEI, 26]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.596 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo I/PressGestureDetector: onAttached begin
2020-08-17 01:36:23.598 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo I/PressGestureDetector: onAttached end
2020-08-17 01:36:23.598 10937-11131/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo I/PressGestureDetector: HiTouch restricted: AboardArea.
2020-08-17 01:36:23.599 10937-11130/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo I/OMXClient: Treble IOmx obtained
2020-08-17 01:36:23.604 10937-11130/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo I/ACodec: In onAllocateComponent create compenent, codec name: OMX.google.hevc.decoder
2020-08-17 01:36:23.617 10937-11134/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo E/BufferQueueProducer: [] Can not get hwsched service
2020-08-17 01:36:23.619 10937-11129/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/SurfaceUtils: connecting to surface 0x7d3548d010, reason connectToSurface
2020-08-17 01:36:23.619 10937-11129/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo I/MediaCodec: [OMX.google.hevc.decoder] setting surface generation to 11199492
2020-08-17 01:36:23.619 10937-11129/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/SurfaceUtils: disconnecting from surface 0x7d3548d010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
2020-08-17 01:36:23.619 10937-11129/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/SurfaceUtils: connecting to surface 0x7d3548d010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
2020-08-17 01:36:23.619 10937-11130/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo W/HwExtendedUtils: hw configLocalPlayBack err = -1010
2020-08-17 01:36:23.620 10937-11130/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo E/ACodec: [OMX.google.hevc.decoder] setPortMode on output to DynamicANWBuffer failed w/ err -1010
2020-08-17 01:36:23.620 10937-11130/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo I/HwExtendedCodec: mime is [video/hevc] at setVideoFormat
2020-08-17 01:36:23.623 10937-11130/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo I/ACodec: codec does not support config priority (err -1010)
2020-08-17 01:36:23.628 10937-11130/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo I/ACodec: onStart
2020-08-17 01:36:23.656 10937-10978/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2020-08-17 01:36:23.668 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger: surfaceSize [eventTime=0.11, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, 1080, 1722]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.714 10937-11129/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/SurfaceUtils: connecting to surface 0x7d33473010, reason connectToSurface
2020-08-17 01:36:23.714 10937-11129/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo I/MediaCodec: [OMX.google.hevc.decoder] setting surface generation to 11199493
2020-08-17 01:36:23.714 10937-11129/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/SurfaceUtils: disconnecting from surface 0x7d33473010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
2020-08-17 01:36:23.714 10937-11129/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/SurfaceUtils: connecting to surface 0x7d33473010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
2020-08-17 01:36:23.715 10937-11129/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/SurfaceUtils: disconnecting from surface 0x7d3548d010, reason disconnectFromSurface
2020-08-17 01:36:23.731 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger: timeline [eventTime=0.17, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=PREPARED
2020-08-17 01:36:23.732 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger:   period [?]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.732 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger:   window [?, false, false]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.732 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger: ]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.756 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger: mediaPeriodCreated [eventTime=0.20, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.758 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger: loading [eventTime=0.20, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, true]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.761 10937-10978/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
2020-08-17 01:36:23.762 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger: timeline [eventTime=0.20, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, periodCount=1, windowCount=1, reason=DYNAMIC
2020-08-17 01:36:23.763 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger:   period [30.10]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.763 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger:   window [30.10, true, false]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.763 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger: ]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.787 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger: decoderEnabled [eventTime=0.23, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, video]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.788 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger: tracks [eventTime=0.23, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0
2020-08-17 01:36:23.788 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger:   Renderer:0 [
2020-08-17 01:36:23.789 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger:     Group:0, adaptive_supported=N/A [
2020-08-17 01:36:23.789 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger:       [X] Track:0, id=1, mimeType=video/hevc, res=1920x1080, supported=YES
2020-08-17 01:36:23.789 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger:     ]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.789 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger:   ]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.789 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger: ]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.794 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger: mediaPeriodReadingStarted [eventTime=0.23, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.795 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger: downstreamFormat [eventTime=0.24, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, id=1, mimeType=video/hevc, res=1920x1080]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.798 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo W/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 1
2020-08-17 01:36:23.820 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger: decoderInitialized [eventTime=0.26, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, video, OMX.google.hevc.decoder]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.821 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger: decoderInputFormat [eventTime=0.26, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, video, id=1, mimeType=video/hevc, res=1920x1080]
2020-08-17 01:36:23.828 10937-10978/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7d37723010 disconnect failed
2020-08-17 01:36:23.828 10937-10978/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7d55764800 (ExpandableListView) with handle 0x7d5575c9a0
2020-08-17 01:36:24.185 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger: loading [eventTime=0.63, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, false]
2020-08-17 01:36:24.258 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger: state [eventTime=0.70, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, true, READY]
2020-08-17 01:36:24.262 10937-10937/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/EventLogger: isPlaying [eventTime=0.70, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, true]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a sample project on Github that works properly with your file. You can check and test it in the link below:

https://github.com/squti/ExoPlayer-MKV-Sample

If you just want to use the codes in your project, first uninstall the previously installed app from your device or emulator and then run the new one.

Here are the essential codes of the project:

> MainActiviy.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PlayerView playerView;
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, new DefaultTrackSelector());
        playerView.setPlayer(player);

        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(
                this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this, getString(R.string.app_name)));
        ProgressiveMediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/jellyfish-3-mbps-hd-h264.mkv"));

        player.prepare(mediaSource);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        playerView.setPlayer(null);
        player.release();
    }
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:resize_mode="fill" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also, you need to add these dependencies to the app level Gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.11.7'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.11.7'
```

I put the video file in the `asset` folder but you can change it base on your needs.

Comment: can you please try with `2.11.7` version.

Comment: I updated the project to 2.11.7 version and it works properly @sanojlawrence

Comment: Please try this file, I was not able to play this file http://jell.yfish.us/media/jellyfish-3-mbps-hd-hevc-10bit.mkv

Comment: The video doesn't play because your device doesn't support 10-bit hevc. It's not the ExoPlayer bug. It's related to device supported decoding capabilities. @sanojlawrence

Comment: But I was able to play the video with other players like Mx player

Comment: Please read this issue on ExoPlayer Github https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3537

Comment: It seems some players manage it with software implementation but ExoPlayer relies on the device capabilities @sanojlawrence

Comment: Let's say if I need to play a 10bit file in low end device, what would be the solution

Comment: On devices without related hardware decoder, you should implement HEVC 10 bit decoder yourself but then you’ll be very limited by the processor and even if you can implement it you will end up with performance issues in the low end devices. Anyway, ExoPlayer hasn't implemented it and you can't do it by this library. @sanojlawrence

Comment: but in MX player they use exoplayer and i was able to play `10 bit file`. And the second issue is no audio is rendering from the sample file .

Comment: Please give me the link that explains MX player using ExoPlayer @sanojlawrence

Comment: Can you help me with audio, with above mentioned sample file

Comment: I played it with VLC on macOS and it doesn't play any audio

Answer (score -1):

Try to make `MediaSource` like this:

```
private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
        new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, "exoplayer");
    return new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
        .createMediaSource(uri);
}
```

Comment: May be u should read this https://stackoverflow.com/q/56661984/3836908