# No file with given name found

Tags: java, android

```
Facemark fm = Face.createFacemarkKazemi();

fm.loadModel("assets/face_landmark_model.dat"); <--error
```

**build.gradle(Module:app):**

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs/'] 
            assets.srcDirs=['src/main/assets/']
} }
```

How fix that?

[image: Project tree structure]

Answer (score 1):

Access the file using assest manager.

```
AssetManager mngr = myContext.getAssets();
fm.loadModel(mngr.open("assets/face_landmark_model.dat"));
```

If you don't have context variable, try to create one.

```
Context context=getApplicationContext();
fm.loadModel(context.getAssets().open("assets/face_landmark_model.dat"));
```

Comment: I get "Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException" in fm.loadModel(mngr.open("assets/face_landmark_model.dat")); 
then I add try and catch block but again have error "No file with given name found"

Comment: If you create the assets folder manually, check the following link.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/26706866/6650476

Comment: can u please add the stack trace and try this fm.loadModel(context.getAssets().open("face_landmark_model.dat"));

Comment: and I convert InputStream to String it is correct [because loadModel(String Model)] ?